# How to connect php to a database in vb application?

Tags: php, sql-server, vb.net, apache

I have a VB application using a Microsoft `SQLServer` Database File on my computer. And I want to access the information from that database online using `PHP`. I already installed Apache and PHP on my computer.

The problem is I don't know how to connect my `PHP` to the database on my VB application.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+sql+server

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408896/connecting-to-an-sql-server-mdf-file-via-php

Answer (score 1):

First of all, take a look at this link concerning [PHP's MS SQL (Microsoft SQL) library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php).

You need to use the MS SQL functions to connect to the database and retrieve the relevant information you require.

I'm not an expert with MS SQL but you'll need code similar to the following:

```
$server = "EDDYSPC\SQLEXPRESS"; // Server address
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "MyDatabase";

$msSQL = mssql_connect($serverm $user, $root);

if (!$msSQL) { // If there was an error connecting to the database
    die("An error occurred.");
}

mssql_select_db($db); // Select the datbase to use

$query = mssql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = 'Eddy'");

while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // Loop through each returned row
    print($row['name'] . "<br />\n");
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I have read the mssql manual. And the problem I have now is what value do I put for $server and $db. My database file is located at C:\Documents and Settings\USER\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\sample\sample\sampledb.mdf

Comment: @tracy Try setting `$server = "localhost";`, `$server = "local";` or `$server = "(local)";`